# How can I execute code only after my view (with its ngFors and the like) has changed?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a MagnificPopup solution to a page full of images. Because they're rendered via an *ngFor, the code to initialise the popup functionality is run before the images have rendered.

Is there a way to run the code only when the view has finished rendering (or, even better, the view contents has changed)? I've seen ways to execute code when a component's @Inputs change, but not when its internal methods do.

Comment: Whenever you have too many elements on a page you should use `changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to prevent lagging and crashing due to heavy load, for more, [see this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37088348/5612697)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built-in support.

You can make your internal fields that `*ngFor` is bound to setters and call methods when they're changed.

Using

```ts
set someValue(newValue) {
  this._someValue = newValue;
  setTimeout(() => afterValueChanged(),10);
}
```

should delay execution of `afterValueChanged()` enough for Angular being done updating the DOM. This way `afterValueChanged()` will be enqueued in the event queue and Angular should be done when this scheduled event queue task is actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (at least, as far as I can tell): ngAfterViewInit.

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

export class Gallery implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('.gallery')['magnificPopup']({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Irrelevant parts of the class ignored, obviously. The square bracket notation calling the method within ngAfterViewInit is needed because the TS compiler complains about missing properties (true at compile-time, but not runtime) when using dot notation.

Comment: can it be that AfterContentInit is needed as it wont wait for the ngFor to be done?

Comment: @eesdil Possibly - it (ngAfterViewInit) certainly appears to work for me thus far, but might not with a greater number of elements in the iterated array.