# Angular 2 fire event after ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin which replaces the default scrollbar inside some dynamic elements in Angular 2.

These elements are created using an `ngFor` loop, that is I cannot attach the jQuery events to the elements these are created.

The application, at some point, mutates an `Observable` object which iscycled inside the `ngFor` in order to render the view.

Now, I would like to know when Angular finishes to draw my elements so that I can run the jQuery plugin.

- I don't want to include any javascript in the HTML template.
- I don't want to use the `ngAfterViewInit`, because this hooks is fired too many times
- I don't want to implement a setTimeout-based solution (I think it's not reliable)

I found a solution by using the following custom `Pipe`: at the end of the `ngFor` cycle in the template, I write:

```
{{i | FireStoreEventPipe:'EVENT_TO_BE_FIRED'}}
```

Where `FireStoreEventPipe` is something like:

```
transform(obj: any, args:any[]) {
    var event = args[0];
    //Fire event
    return null;
}
```

But this solution does not satisfy me.

Any suggestion for a better way?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't think this is a duplicate add a comment to get it reopened.

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate, because I can't use `ngAfterViewInit` (I tried but it's not ok for me, because it's fired too many times), and I was looking for something better than setTimeout-based solution (that are not reliable). I'll edit my question with these details

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit()` is only called once AFAIK I guess it is not often enough. I don't think you'll get another result because Angular doesn't provide anything to call after `ngFor` updates the DOM. I'd check if the is an issue for this in the GitHub repo otherwise create one.

Comment: I think it's a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011948/how-can-i-execute-code-only-after-my-view-with-its-ngfors-and-the-like-has-cha

Comment: you want to call function when `*ngFor` Complete its task ?

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819264/angular-2-callback-when-ngfor-has-finished

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.
I am using angular2 rc 1.

I solved it by creating a new component(a directive didnt work for me).

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'islast',
   template: '<span></span>'
})
export class LastDirective {
   @Input() isLast: boolean;
   @Output() onLastDone: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
   ngOnInit() {
      if (this.isLast)
        this.onLastDone.emit(true);
   }
}
```

Then i imported in my wanted component as child component in the directives:

```
directives: [LastDirective],
```

In html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let sm of filteredMembers; let last = last; let i=index;" data-id="{{sm.Id}}">
     <td>
        <islast [isLast]="last" (onLastDone)="modalMembersDone()"></islast>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

And of course implement modalMembersDone()