# Getting Child Component of tbody

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am not able to access Table Row of Data in Angular 2 Application,using Element Ref and query Selector.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
            var e1 = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("tbody");
                        console.log(e1);
                e1.draggable="true";
    }
```

Above Code shows Data with tbody and child tr.

However,when I use

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
            var e1 = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
                        console.log(e1);
                e1.draggable="true";
    }
```

The Result is Coming As Null or Blank Array.[]

Comment: What do you want to select with `tbody tr` ? If all `tr`s under `tbody` then `<tr>`s might not have been present by the time you call this command. Try to setTimeout in like 5-6 seconds to test it.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a NodeList array. If you need only the first child get the first element of this list, if it exists, like querySelectorAll("tbody tr")[0]

Comment: @echonax....Even I am thinking the same and set TimeOut does Resolve the Issue,but It delays Other things mid way.Is there any Other functionality you are Aware of in Angular 2 which can help me getting Thing done in a smoother way.

Comment: @user3856563 where do you inject `<tr>`s? Is it with an ngFor? What is the use case?

Comment: @echonax...yes....my tr is in inline with  ngFor.

Comment: These might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819264/angular-2-callback-when-ngfor-has-finished, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482343/angular-2-fire-event-after-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Where `querySelector` works for you is because it returns DOM ( as you said data was returned ).

But with querySelctorAll you will get Node list. So, try to iterate trough that list and you will get table rows.

```
e1.forEach(tr => console.log(tr));
```

Comment: @haris...Tried the same but getting tbody in the response.I think the Issue is with rendering of DOM,which is taking time.
But I am not able to figure out how to resolve that,