# execute a function when *ngFor finished in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I trying to create a application with angular 2,i want when last element rendered in *ngFor,execute a function, somthing like this :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#i of items">{{i.text}}</li> <==== i want when this completed, execute a functuon in my class
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what you actually want to last element of *ngFor ? do you want to perfrom some action like *ngIf on last element ?

Comment: i want call slider function...i tried ngAfterViewinit or something like this but dont worked...when i use setTimeout() it is worked but is not a good idea...
what do you think i should do?

Comment: ohh  no setTimeOut is not an good idea, really interesting question just wait ill try and give you answer within few minutes.

Comment: Do you want to call your method only aftwr the first time then list is rendered? Or should it be called again if, for example, you add/remove an item in the list?

Answer (score 79):

## Update

You can use `@ViewChildren` for that purpose

There are three cases

**1.** on initialization `ngFor` element is not rendred due to `ngIf` on it or it's parent

- in which case, whenver `ngIf` becomes truthy, you will be notified by the `ViewChildren` subscription

**2.**   on initialization `ngFor` element is rendred regardless of `ngIf` on it or it's parent

- in which case `ViewChildren` subscription will not notify you for the first time, but you can be sure it's rendered in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook

**3.**   items are added/removed to/from the `ngFor` Array

- in which case also `ViewChildren` subscription will notify you

[**[Plunker Demo]**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RTasC4b0Q0H5zOu7TbXW?p=preview) *(see console log there)*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <ul *ngIf="!isHidden">
          <li #allTheseThings *ngFor="let i of items; let last = last">{{i}}</li>
        </ul>
        
        <br>
        
        <button (click)="items.push('another')">Add Another</button>
        
        <button (click)="isHidden = !isHidden">{{isHidden ? 'Show' :  'Hide'}}</button>
      `,
})
export class App {
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

  @ViewChildren('allTheseThings') things: QueryList < any > ;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.things.changes.subscribe(t => {
      this.ngForRendered();
    })
  }

  ngForRendered() {
    console.log('NgFor is Rendered');
  }
}
```

---

## Original

You can do it like this ( but see [the side Effects for yourself](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1M8yhn0g08BMUsxc1nF?p=preview) )

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of items; let last = last">{{i}} {{last ? callFunction(i) : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

Which is **Useless,** unless used with [**changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush**](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Then you can have control over how many times change detection occurs, hence how many times your function is called.

***i.e:*** You can trigger next `changeDetection` when the data of `items` changes, and your function will give proper indication that `ngFor` is rendered for **real change**.

Comment: this answer is better as it does not create a `span`

Comment: @smnbbrv haha no need to create extra `span` in my answer too, i have created just for trying something new :p but did't got successful.

Comment: but you'll have to take care of the function calls, it's going to be called every time change detection ticks

Comment: @PardeepJain yep, I know :) Still the answer is the answer. And still the function is going to be called so many times... I don't really think the author's intention is a good way

Comment: yups @smnbbrv totally agreed with your point. even i am shocked why function called too many times trying to figure out whats the reason, when found ill update my answer.

Comment: @A_Singh did you know why change detection runs 8 times ,i mean alert poping up 8 times why ?

Comment: because recursion maybe, ngFor renders and at last calls the function, that ticks change detection, which triggers ngFor to render again and call the function again, and so on. I'm not sure why it would stop after 8

Comment: me niether, let's just wait for Gunter or Thierry's answer

Comment: haha exactly well said @A_Singh waiting for angular2 king's answer.

Comment: why this function always repeat?????
i test it with an alert and i get in a loop...and my function repeat!!!!

Comment: read the comments [on this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37088348/5612697) you will understand

Comment: One simple but shabby work-around is to use a boolean to determine whether to run your function. It will still check the bool a million times but the cost of that is minute by comparison. In my case, I just set it to false and left it since I only needed to run the function once upon completion of the *ngFor

Comment: Requesting an up to date and more complete example for future viewers.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version Singh. It works perfectly, and doesn't feel hacky.

Comment: Glad, that I could help :)

Answer (score 9):

I used a slight hack of the approach others have complained about and it worked like a charm:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of items; let last = last">{{i}} {{last ? callFunction(i) : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then in your component:

```
shouldDoIt = true; // initialize it to true for the first run

callFunction(stuff) {
    if (this.shouldDoIt) {
        // Do all the things with the stuff
        this.shouldDoIt = false; // set it to false until you need to trigger again
    }
}
```

This doesn't address the root of the problem with this approach but it's an extremely low-cost hack that made my app run smoothly. I do hope the Angular team will implement a more friendly way to trigger some code after the *ngFor loads its content.

Answer (score 3):

you can do the same by getting last index using `#last` of `*ngFor` and call function by getting last index value and do your stuff whatever you want. here is code for the same -

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#item of items; #last = last">
    <span *ngIf='last'>{{hello(last)}}</span>
    {{item}}
   </li>
  </ul>


items: Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5]
  constructor() { console.clear();}
  hello(a){
    if(a==true)
      this.callbackFunction();
  }
  callbackFunction(){
    console.log("last element");
  }
```

working example for the same <kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SilCpiT36gxdtI97cW0c?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: this function always execute!like a loop!

Comment: @AlirezaValizade yes read `@A_singh's` answer's comments for more clerfification

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. In my case I was calling a web service to retrieve data and needed to execute javascript to initialize each template produced by `*ngFor`. Here's what I came up with:

```
updateData() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
    function(data) {
      this.data = data;
      setTimeout(javascriptInitializationFunction, 0);
    },
    function(err) { /* handle it */ }
  );
}
```

`setTimout` will wait for the DOM To be updated before executing. This isn't exactly what you asked, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: It's working but in many cases it would produce a kind of hacky experience. For example if the data is showing products in the DOM, and you need to make design change with a JavaScript function (instead of your `javascriptInitializationFunction`). This solution would create a glimps of the products (data) before the javascript function would be runned. I had this experience with implementing [Gridify](https://github.com/hongkhanh/gridify) in an Angular application.

Comment: You can implement the accepted answer in this solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same question and find one way to walk around this. Not sure whether it is suitable for you or not. 
Pre-conditions is you are using ngFor to render inbound properties.

context: I need call MDL's upgradeAllRegistered to make checkbox pretty after fetch grid data from back-end.

I add one setTimeout inside 'ngOnChanges';

grid.componet.ts:

```
export class GridComponent {
  @Input() public rows: Array<any>;
    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      if (propName == 'rows') {
        setTimeout(() => componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

grid.component.html:

```
<tr #rowDOM *ngFor="let row of rows;"></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd managed to perform some hacks to prevent event get triggred (I found that scrolling always trigger those events)

By adding : [Add in your component]

```
private globalFlag = -1;
```

and this is my event that will be triggered when looping is finished

```
ev(flag){
    if(flag != this.globalFlag){
      console.log("TRIGGER!")
      this.globalFlag = flag;

    }
  }
```

and this the looping code

```
 <div *ngFor="let var of list;let i=index;let last=last">
    {{last ? ev(i) : ''}}
</div>
```

The main idea is to prevent event be trigger if the flag was same. So it only be trigger when the globalFlag value differed with current flag that passed from ngFor. Sorry for my bad english, hope you can understand my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: the answer is displayed on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phpauq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
 html = '';
ngAfterViewInit(){
       let  i;
       this.html += '<ul>';
       for(i = 0 ; i < this.abc.length ; i++){
           this.html += '<li>';
           this.html +=  this.abc[i];
           if(parseInt(i) === this.abc.length - 1){
           this.callMethod(i);
           }
           this.html += '</li>';
           }
           this.html += '</ul>';
    }


    callMethod(text){
    alert(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this technique which worked well for my case:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index;">
     {{ ( (!flag) && ( (i+1) ===  itemList.length) ) ? myFunction() : ''}}
</div>
```

In my .js code :

```
let flag : boolean = false;

myFunction()
{
   // To execute if ngFor has finished
   this.flag = true;
}
```