# execute a function evertime ngFor is finished displaying data

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am trying to call a function everytime my ngFor is done loading data from my API.

but the callback is only triggering on first load of the ngFor.

how can I execute the callback everytime my ngFor is changed;

I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38214091/6647448

here is what I have so far...

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" (click)="changeDate()"></button>

<div *ngFor="item of items; let last = last">
    <div>{{item}}{{last ? ngForAfterInit() : ''}}</div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
this.ngForIsFinished = true;

ngForAfterInit() {
    if (this.ngForIsFinished) {
        this.ngForIsFinished = false;
    }
}

changeDate() {
    // this is where i trigger my ngFor to change its content
}
```

The person who answered said that you just need to set the `ngForIsFinished` back to `true` but I am having a hard time where to set it on my code.

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? What do you hope to achieve by knowing when the `ngFor` is rerendered?

Comment: if the ngFor is rerendered the callback function `ngForAfterInit` will be executed

Comment: show complete `changeDate()`

Comment: @AdritaSharma my changeDate() requests on my API to get data to be displayed

Comment: @AdritaSharma the `changeDate()` is a function where another request is made on my API and displayed on my ngFor.

Comment: Have you tried using the method used in the most voted answer in the link you have provided?

Comment: @nash11 i tried it but it throws me an error on viewChildren

Comment: I think you should try that method rather than the "hack" and show the errors you get when you try that method.

Comment: @nash11 I tried the method it works well. but the data rendered by my first ngFor is also included on my newly rendered ngFor. I am using .push()

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. How is the data rendered by your first `ngFor` is also included in the newly rendered `ngFor` when all you're trying to do is find out when the `ngFor` is rerendered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200343/discussion-between-terence-and-nash11).

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819264/angular-2-callback-when-ngfor-has-finished

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and `last` variable of `ngFor`. Because `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` always checks methods, so `fooMethod(...)` will be called multiple items:

```
<div *ngFor = "let title of iterated; let i=index; let last=last">
  {{last ? fooMethod(last) : '' }}  
</div>
```

yourComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';

  iteratedData = [
      {"title":"test1","description":"foo","name":"name1"}, 
      {"title":"test2","description":"foo","name":"name2"}, 
      {"title":"test3","description":"foo","name":"name3"}, 
      {"title":"test4","description":"foo","name":"name4"}
  ];

  fooMethod(v) {
    if (v)
      console.log(`This is from the method ${v}`);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

After you've loaded data you should call slice method as Angular 2 change detection strategy doesn't check the contents of arrays or object. So try to create a copy of the array after mutation:

```
this.iteratedData.push(newItem);
this.iteratedData = this.iteratedData.slice();
```

OR:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

And you can call a method `markForCheck` to trigger a `changeDetection`:

```
this.iteratedData.push(newItem);
this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
```

Comment: The ngFor doesn't load when I implemented changeDetection

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

Component:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
        })
        export class AppComponent  {
          name = 'Angular 5';
          data:any = [];

          ngAfterViewInit(){
            this.changeDate();

          }

          ngForAfterInit(valuue) {
            alert('FOR LOOP COMPLETED : '+ valuue);
           }


           ChangeDate(){
              let i = 0;
              setInterval(()=>{
                this.data=[];
                for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
                 this.data.push("TEST DATA "+ j+" SET AT :  "+i);
               };
               i+=1;
            },7000);
          }
       }
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let last=last;">
{{item}} {{last? ngForAfterInit(item) :''}}
</div>
```

SetInterval is like your API which will assign data.This is working for me

https://stackblitz.com/edit/pokemon-app-4n2shk